# Any logical explanation behind android naming convention ?

Tags: android, coding-style

I am wondering that could be a logical explanation behind:

> Non-public, non-static field names start with m.

in Android
https://source.android.com/source/code-style

Comment: Maybe it stands for member

Answer (score 0):

This way you can see if something is field or local variable even in notepad or any other editor without colors.

Comment: It is not the case with regular Java, I don't think this is the case.

Comment: This is helping me during code reviews. This is jus convention like camel case. If you are used to it, it looks od when its not there.